# MSTest C++ unit test dll not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

**C# Unit Test - Runs ok**

I have read the MSTest unit test (utterly useless )documentation on the microsoft website here: [utterly-useless-ms-doc-link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182487.aspx). Then I read a whole load of other more useful links (e.g. on SO) and finally I am able to run **C#** unit tests no problems, like this:

```
mstest /testcontainer:UnitTest.dll /detail:errormessage
```

**C++ Unit Test - Fails**

As far as I can tell this should be the same for the C++ unit tests, so I ran a similar command (specific command details at the end) for C++, but then I get the error:

> UnitTest_TrackManager.dll Unable to load the test container
>   'UnitTest_TrackManager.dll' or one of its dependencies. If you build
>   your test project assembly as a 64 bit assembly, it cannot be loaded.
>   When you build your test project assembly, select "Any CPU" for the
>   platform. To run your tests in 64 bit mode on a 64 bit processor, you
>   must change your test settings in the Hosts tab to run your tests in a
>   32 bit process. Error details: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///D:\MiddlewareTest01\x64\Debug\UnitTest_TrackManager.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
>   assembly manifest.

**32-bit or 64-bit DLL?**

So, fair enough, I have built the code for 64 bit and MStest is 32bit only. I used `dumpbin /HEADERS fname.dll` to check that this is a 64-bit file and it is:

```
File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               D number of sections
        5829E628 time date stamp Mon Nov 14 16:28:24 2016
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
            2022 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL
```

So, then I recompie for 32-bit and run the test again, but I get the same error. So I check that the file output (the DLL) is 32-bit and it does appear to be, here is the dumpbin for that:

```
File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               C number of sections
        5829E792 time date stamp Mon Nov 14 16:34:26 2016
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
            2102 characteristics
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine
                   DLL
```

**C++ Unit Test Works in the IDE**

Using MSVS2015 IDE, I can compile and run my code/unit tests and they all work (when I use the x86 build) - and they all pass. If I select x64 build then it complains.

**Specific Command That Fails**

Here is the exact command line I am useing:

`mstest /testcontainer:UnitTest_TrackManager.dll /detail:errormessage`

It is run from the same location as the dll lives which is here:

`D:\<somepath>\MiddlewareTest01\Debug\UnitTest_TrackManager.dll`

Where `<somepath>` is just there to hide my PC/user details and `MiddlewareTest01` is the solution folder.

As I say, I can get this to work for C# projects, but for C++ it does not seem to work in the same way.

**Update**

Using dependency-walker it tells me:

`MICROSOFT.VISUALSTUDIO.TESTTOOLS.CPPUNITTESTFRAMEWORK.DLL` was not found. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Interesting - almost exactly the same issue I just ran into - Did you simply put the required DLL (CPPUNITTESTFRAMEWORK) on the path?

Comment: Ok found how to run the tests on the command line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604691/running-native-vs2012-c-64-bit-unit-tests-from-command-line?rq=1